# Is latexdiff-vc -r inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: latexdiff

I often use `latexdiff-vc -r <rev>` but I always wondered if `<rev>` is inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. It will compare revision <rev> with the current file.  I would say that it is inclusive but not sure if your definition matches mine

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is whether the changes in <rev> (say from `git show <rev>) would be included in the output pdf diff. Is that any clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it compares the same files as `git diff <rev>` would (i.e. `<rev>` can be a commit, a branch name, a named tag or HEAD, comparison is always with the file in working directory). I think this means it's inclusive (i.e. the changes committed will already been taken into account) - it will not show the changes committed in this commit.

If you want to show the changes applied in the commit the following ought to work:

`latexdiff-git -r<commit>^ -r<commit>`